# How can I overlay a "play button" over a VR Video?

Tags: android, google-vr

**I want to add a giant white play button on top of the video for both VR and non-VR modes of my `VrVideoView`. How do I tell when I'm in VR view?**

I'm using `com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView` to handle playing the video both with and without the headset on.

---

My thought process so far:

- I have no way to check/bind to when someone goes in and out of VR mode, so I don't know when to add one versus two play buttons over the video.
- So given the above, I've thought about modifying the video programmatically to achieve this. Is that my only choice?

Comment: I'm facing same problem cannot find solution so far.. please let me know if you find something..

Comment: answered. Thanks for commenting on this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up having the video edited to add a play button to the first frame.

*It's not possible to be notified of when the user enters/exits VR mode.*

Here's why: The Android Google **Cardboard VR SDK** is built to be accessible for easy integration in content-viewing apps. It is not built to be used in a custom-VR video viewing application. [Here's a thread on **Github** about the topic](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/9)

Due to the limitations above, we very quickly rewrote the application in **Unity** (still using **Cardboard SDK**)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extend the VrVideoView and dismiss the button in the create methods, like this:

```
public EHVideoPlayerPano(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) 
{
    super(context, attributeSet);
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < frameLayout.getChildCount(); i++) 
    {
        Object view = frameLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof RelativeLayout) 
        {
            //hide the botton
            ((RelativeLayout) view).setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    }
}
```